# git stash push <file> doesn't only save the specified file

Tags: git

In `man git-stash`, `git stash push` is explained as below:

```
push [-p|--patch] [-S|--staged] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all]
[-q|--quiet] [-m|--message <message>] [--pathspec-from-file=<file> [--pathspec-file-nul]] [--]
[<pathspec>...]

    Save your local modifications to a new stash entry and roll them back to HEAD (in the working
    tree and in the index). The <message> part is optional and gives the description along with
    the stashed state.
```

where `<pathspec>` is

```
<pathspec>...

    This option is only valid for push command.

    The new stash entry records the modified states only for the files that match the pathspec.
    The index entries and working tree files are then rolled back to the state in HEAD only for
    these files, too, leaving files that do not match the pathspec intact.
```

So `git stash push -- <file>` should only save `<file>` as a stash entry, right?

However, as far as I tested, `git stash push -- <file>` saves everything (i.e. not limited to `<file>`):

```sh
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   LICENSE.md
    modified:   README.md
    modified:   src/attach.ts

$ git stash push -- README.md
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: ccd0b050 fix(highlight): use coc#compat#buf_line_count

$ git status #This is as expected.
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   LICENSE.md
    modified:   src/attach.ts

$ git stash show #Why? This is not what I expect.
 LICENSE.md    | 2 +-
 README.md     | 2 +-
 src/attach.ts | 1 +
 3 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at ccd0b050 fix(highlight): use coc#compat#buf_line_count

$ git status #This is as expected.
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git stash pop #Strangely, not only `README.md` is restored.
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   LICENSE.md
    modified:   README.md
    modified:   src/attach.ts

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (0ee651d4a9206e2e8ce384ca6623175fa3edcdcd)
```

How can this be explained?

Environments: macOS with git 2.35.1 (installed via brew), Arch Linux with git 2.35.1

Comment: That appears to be a bug. You might submit it in a bug report.

Comment: @torek Can you reproduce this behavior? I wonder if this is due to my environments (I tested under macOS and Arch Linux, both with git 2.35.1).

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but I think LeGEC's answer explains the *actual* behavior: Git is accidentally using the primary index, when for this particular case, it *should* be creating and using a temporary index. I believe this may be a bug introduced in the conversion from shell script to C code. If so, backing down to a Git version that has `git stash push`, but still uses the script, will behave differently.

Comment: @torek Do you know when (or in what version) was Git converted to C code? I googled some phrases (e.g. "git rewritten in c") but got no information about it.

Comment: It's `git stash` specifically, not Git as a whole: Git itself has always been written in a mix of shell script and C code. The scripts are very slow on Windows so more and more of them have been converted to C code over time. (Meanwhile there have been Java and Python and Go and other implementations of Git, some of which sometimes call out to the "original" Git and some of which never do.) But the answer is in the release notes: `grep stash Documentation/RelNotes/2.2?.*` => `Documentation/RelNotes/2.22.0.txt: * "git stash" has been rewritten in C.`

Comment: @torek Thank you! I compiled both the tag `v2.22.0` and `v2.21.0` to check the difference. As you say, `git stash` in `v2.21.0` is written in shell script. I checked it using `file ./git-stash` command. However, as for the problem we're discussing now, the result was that the same behavior was observed even in `v2.21.0`. Anyway, I just sent a bug report to Git's mailing list.

Comment: Interesting. At least the behavior is consistent then. Maybe this is the desired behavior (on the part of others using `git stash`), but it seems wrong to me in terms of the description of `git stash` with pathspecs.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR : I think git stash starts by storing the complete index, so if your files are staged for commit before you run `git stash push -- <paths...>`, you will have the complete index stored in the stash.

---

Starting from the following setup :

```
$ git init
$ echo aaa > a.txt && echo bbb > b.txt
$ git add a.txt b.txt
$ git commit -m "first commit"

$ echo aaa >> a.txt  # add a line to a.txt
$ echo bbb >> b.txt  # add a line to b.txt
```

```
# repo state after the above setup :
$ git status -s
 M a.txt
 M b.txt
$ git stash show
No stash entries found.
```

---

If the files are *not* staged before stashing, stashing only one file works as we would expect :

```
$ git stash push -- a.txt
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: c652c35 first commit

# index and stash content are as is expected :
$ git status -s
 M b.txt
$ git stash show
 a.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git log --oneline --graph --name-status --cc stash
*   07770c0 (refs/stash) WIP on master: c652c35 first commit
|\  
| | 
MM      a.txt
| * 58d58bf index on master: c652c35 first commit
|/  
* c652c35 (HEAD -> master) first commit
...
```

If the files are *staged before stashing*, though (and I think this is the situation you describe ?), it looks like `git stash` starts with writing the complete index :

```
$ git add a.txt b.txt 
$ git stash push -- a.txt
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: c652c35 first commit
$ git status -s
M  b.txt
$ git stash show
 a.txt | 1 +
 b.txt | 1 +
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
$ git log --oneline --graph --name-only --cc stash
*   1a10665 (refs/stash) WIP on master: c652c35 first commit
|\  
| | 
| * c26f4a2 index on master: c652c35 first commit
|/  
|   M   a.txt   # the complete index is stashed
|   M   b.txt
* c652c35 (HEAD -> master) first commit
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I could reproduce your explanation. But I don't understand the reason yet... As you say, the index is first saved and then the working directory is saved. However, when `git stash push -- a.txt`, `b.txt` is saved in the first commit in the stash entry though it is still staged after the command. This is extremely counter-intuitive, IMO. I also noticed the commits generated by `git stash push` and `git stash push -- a.txt` are *exactly* the same (checked by `git show <commit hash>`). This means the `-- <file>` parameter doesn't change the way how stash entry is created at all...

Comment: @ynn : you will see a difference if, on top of having a staged version for `a.txt` and `b.txt`, you *also* have modifications in the worktree (e.g : `git add a.txt b.txt; echo "one more line" >> a.txt; echo "one more line" >> b.txt`). You may report that the behavior of `git stash` regarding the index in that situation is unclear and undocumented.

Comment: I confirmed that is correct. Tonight or tomorrow I'll summarize the behaviors and issue a bug report.